# Controls removed from WebForms page come back during PostBack! How to prevent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the opposite problem to most people. On an ASP.NET WebForms page, In Page_Load, I am removing a bunch of controls from the UI. All of these removed controls are otherwise contained within ASP.NET Panel controls. They are removed using (`Panel.Controls.Clear()`). There are some postback mechanisms on the page, eg: buttons, autoposting dropdowns, etc.

The problem is that on postback, the controls that were removed are back! I tried enabling ViewState, disabling it, for these panels. But they are just back.

How do I ensure that the removed controls stay removed?

PS: Re-evaluating the requirement to remove is costly since [1] there are many such controls and [2] all of them involve going to the database backend.

**EDIT: Adding code to illustrate:**

Actual code is pretty large and complicated, posting an abbreviated version for understanding:

In Page_Load:

```
if (! IsPostBack) 
{

    /// ... code to retrieve data & populate to existingItems

    // if existingItems dropdownlist is empty, clear the panel and add notice message.
    if (existingItems.Items.Count > 0) // existingItems is a dropdownlist
    {
        existingItemsContainerPanel.Controls.Clear();
        existingItemsContainerPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("No items found!"));
    }
}
```

When the page first runs with an empty dataset, the controls are cleared correctly and the notice message is set. When any submit button on the page is clicked, the controls that were cleared from the existingItemsContainerPanel panel all reappear. And of course, the added literal control is also missing at postback.

Based off @Scotty's answer below, I tried setting all the controls within the panel to `Visible = false`, but this has the same issue as well. The controls are visible on postback.

**Observation**: From reference source for Control.LoadViewState (see: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/Control.cs,d09938bb5b5567f5) if you click through where the methods are called, it does not appear the Panel control calls LoadViewStateRecursive on postback. It is only called when the internal controls collection seems to be modified. So may be this should be written away as a .net framework feature/bug and left to developers to implement their own way to manage viewstate!

Comment: please show your code behind and html markup to make it possible for others to help you. as a start, do you have if(!Postback) in your page_load event?

Comment: if (existingItems.Items.Count > 0)  this means if items in the dropdowns are exists and not empty

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
controlID.Visible = false;
```

instead to hide the control across postbacks.

As long as you're not data binding your controls on each postback, performance should not be hindered using this approach as the control's HTML is not rendered on the page using this method.

Comment: Ok, do you have EnableViewState="false" in your aspx page directive by any chance? To me it just sounds like your viewstate is disabled. We'll need to see your markup as well as your code behind to be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: EnableViewState is at default values, they are not explicitly set anywhere in the page hierarchy.